# Break the encapsulation of immediately executed anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript

A common Javascript pattern is:

```
(function() {
  var localScopedValue = "foobar";
  // code... functions...
}());
```

The self-executing or immediately executed anonymous function creates a scope for everything inside it to prevent pollution of the global scope, and it also theoretically prevents anyone from getting references to either the function object or anything defined inside it from an outside script, browser console, etc. That's the idea, anyway.

However, Javascript being a dynamic language with reflection, etc., I am wondering if there is any way -- no matter how hackish (but not editing any existing code) -- of getting references to locals that are not deliberately exposed from Javascript code.

Reason: pure curiosity / breaking things.

Adding: Things I'm looking at include `Function.caller` and event listeners, basically anything where items inside the IIFE are known to call/hook out, but I can't put together the complete package.

Comment: As you didn't use the `var` keyword, you've just created a global variable, and it *is* accessible outside the IIFE ?

Comment: Forgetting var was a mistake

Comment: No. There's no way to access the private variables of an IIFE if they are not accidentally exposed from pure JavaScript.

Comment: you can always walk the call stack to learn whats happening above you... `(function() { console.log(arguments.callee.caller) })()`

Comment: Typically you would create a single global object (like jquery does for example) and all of your stuff you want exposed is exposed on that object. Everything else is stored in the closures of the immediate function that created that object.

Comment: Is your sandbox compromised? Why is this important?

Answer (score 1):

JS doesn't have "real" reflection - all it has is the ability to access the properties of an object using a variable as a key with `myObject[myVar]` syntax instead of `myObject.myProperty`.

This therefore provides no access to *lexically scoped* private variables.

Comment: If you want to go really crazy though, you can walk the stack and `toString` the functions. It won't get you the locals, but it'll give you their names at least. Dunno how you would go about getting the values from that though.

Comment: @Alxandr AFAIK you can only do that if you're already within that stack trace, which also implies that the variables are in scope (albeit not "automatically discoverable")

Comment: Yup. So you have to use something that's callback based where you pass it an evil "inspect" function. On the other hand. Lots of stuff have callbacks... It could also be doable by replacing certain global functions before the creation of the IIFE with "proxy" functions that stored the "scope" and returned the original value.

Comment: @Alxandr I don't think that would work - functions supplied as callbacks don't have access to the local variables because they're _lexically_ scoped.

Comment: Yes, but as said, they have access to the caller.